# Getting a .wav file data without writing on disk in Python

Tags: python, audio, io

I am trying to get recording samples where I want to save the stream of bytes into memory rather than on disk. When I write on disk, it works. However, I tried saving it in memory and it is not working. The following code works when saving on disk. But I want to have a work out where I don't need to save the `audio.wav` file first but have a flow where it is temporary saved in memory at least.

```
val = st_audiorec()

if isinstance(val, dict):  # retrieve audio data
    with st.spinner('retrieving audio-recording...'):
        ind, val = zip(*val['arr'].items())
        ind = np.array(ind, dtype=int)  # convert to np array
        val = np.array(val)             # convert to np array
        sorted_ints = val[ind]
        stream = BytesIO(b"".join([int(v).to_bytes(1, "big") for v in sorted_ints]))
        wav_bytes = stream.read()
    
        # get the format of the audio as wav or mp3
        with open("audio.wav", "wb") as audio_file:
             audio_file.write(wav_bytes)
```

I do not want to save the file on the disk but rather save it in memory from the `wav_bytes` variable so I can pass it on later to some `inference` function.
The full code is available on my [github](https://github.com/jpandeinge/streamlit_whisper_transcribe)